# How to make volume range calculation more RAM friendly?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to find out the mean, media and percentile ranges of price movements for a given volume to be filled using trade data. Attaching the code below. The problem is that the code gives me wsfull error when i run it on ~80k records. I am using a 4g linux box. At the moment I can only run it for ~30k records and even then q uses >70% of my ram.
Is there any way to make it more memory friendly?

```
rangeForVol : {[symIn; vol; dt] 
data: select from table where sym=symIn, date=dt;    
data: update cumVol: sums quantity, cVol: sums quantity from data;
data: update cumVolTgt: cumVol + vol from data;
data: update pxLst: price[where each ((cumVol>=/:cVol) and (cumVol<=/:cumVolTgt))=1] from data;
.Q.gc[];
data: update minPx: min each pxLst, maxPx: max each pxLst from data;
data: update range: maxPx - minPx from data;
data
};
select count i by floor range%0.5 from rangeForVol[`ABC; 2500; 2012.06.04]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you quote above almost certainly does not do what you were trying to achieve.

The column cumVol and cVol are both identical (in that they contain a running total of that day's volume). Later you calculate `cumVol>=/:cVol`. `/:` means that for every element in cVol you will compare it to the *entire* vector cumVol. As they are identical, you will get the identity matrix (plus some extra 1b for any non-distinct values).

```
q)(til 4)=\:til 4
1000b
0100b
0010b
0001b
```

It seems you wanted to perform an element-wise comparison between the two vectors (though comparing a vector to itself also doesn't make sense), and if you want to do this explicitly, each-both would be the correct adverb (`='`). However, in q, the `=` operator will implicitly apply item-wise to two vectors of the same length (or a vector and a scalar, as is happening in your each-left example), making any adverb unnecessary.

The fact you are creating two n x n matrices when you probably intended a length n vector is probably the reason you're running out of memory.